# Bob the (Graph) Builder

Tags: c#, graph

I'm starting a project in which I'll generate random graphs and use algorithms to solve them. The first necessary step is obviously to build a graph.

My graph has the following characteristics :

1. It can be directional or not, implying that the `Edge` between `NodeA` and `NodeB` can be traversed from `B to A` if the `Graph` is `NonDirectional`.
2. The `Edge` can be "weighted", meaning that there's an `int` value linked to an edge, which will be used for some graph algorithms.

At the moment, I have mostly tested the **non directional weighted** graph, so it's the one I'll put for review. I hav removed the header comments from the class/methods as I have multiple classes to show.

```
public class Node : IEquatable<Node>
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public Node(string name)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) throw new ArgumentException("Name cannot be null or empty", nameof(name));

        Name = name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Node);
    }

    public bool Equals(Node other)
    {
        return Name == other.Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode() * 23; 
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"({this.GetType().Name}) - Name : {Name}";
    }
}
```

Note : The `PriorityQueueNode` base class is used in the algorithms, but it is not used anywhere in this review. The `AssociationId` is used in case of a non directional graph, it is used to see if two edges are from the same... association (`A to B` and `B to A`).

```
public class Edge : PriorityQueueNode, IEquatable<Edge>
{
    private readonly Lazy<int> computedHashCode;

    public Guid AssociationId { get; }
    public Node From { get; }
    public Node To { get; }

    public Edge(Node from, Node to, Guid associationId)
    {
        if (to == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(to));
        if (from == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(from));

        From = from;
        To = to;
        AssociationId = associationId;

        //Since Edge is immutable, hash can be computed once.
        computedHashCode = new Lazy<int>(() => (From.GetHashCode() * 17) ^ (To.GetHashCode() * 17) ^ (AssociationId.GetHashCode() * 17));
    }

    public bool ConnectsSameNode(Edge edge)
    {
        if (edge == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(edge));

        if (AssociationId == edge.AssociationId) return true;

        bool connectsSameFrom = edge.From.Equals(From) || edge.To.Equals(From);

        return connectsSameFrom && (edge.From.Equals(To) || edge.To.Equals(To));
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Edge);
    }

    public bool Equals(Edge edge)
    {
        if (edge == null) return false;

        return AssociationId == edge.AssociationId && From.Equals(edge.From) && To.Equals(edge.To);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return computedHashCode.Value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"({this.GetType().Name}) - From : {From.Name}, To : {To.Name}, AssociationId : {AssociationId}";
    }
}

public class WeightedEdge : Edge, IEquatable<WeightedEdge>, IComparable<WeightedEdge>
{
    public int Weight { get; }

    public WeightedEdge(Node from, Node to, int weight, Guid associationId)
        : base(from, to, associationId)
    {
        if (weight <= 0) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(weight)} must be higher than zero", nameof(weight));

        Weight = weight;
    }

    public int CompareTo(WeightedEdge other)
    {
        if (other == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("other");

        int compareValue = Math.Sign(Weight - other.Weight);

        //Compare AssociationId because something needs to decide the priority and it can't be random.
        return compareValue == 0 ? AssociationId.CompareTo(other.AssociationId) : compareValue;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as WeightedEdge);
    }

    public bool Equals(WeightedEdge edge)
    {
        return base.Equals(edge) && edge.Weight == Weight;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode() ^ (Weight.GetHashCode() * 13);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{base.ToString()}, Weight : {Weight}";
    }
}
```

That is it for the structure of a `Graph`. Now, the `Graph` class. I use a `ICollectionDictionary<Node,T>` to hold my graph, the interface is defined as this :

```
public interface ICollectionDictionary<T,TK> : IDictionary<T, ICollection<TK>>
{
    void AddToCollection(T key, TK value);

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new empty ICollection for the T key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Key.</param>
    void InitializeKeyCollection(T key);
}
```

I'll leave the implementation out of the review as the question gets long already, but I'll add a link to the GitHub repo at the end.

```
public interface IGraph<T> where T : Edge
{
    bool IsDirectional { get; }
    int NodesCount { get; }
    int EdgesCount { get; }
    IEnumerable<Node> Nodes { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> GetEdges(Node node);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAllUniquesEdges();
}

public class Graph<T> : IGraph<T> where T : Edge
{
    private readonly ICollectionDictionary<Node, T> _map;
    private bool _isDirectional;

    public int NodesCount => _map.Keys.Count;
    public int EdgesCount => _map.Values.Count;

    public bool IsDirectional => _isDirectional;

    public IEnumerable<Node> Nodes => _map.Keys.ToList();

    internal Graph(ICollectionDictionary<Node, T> map, bool isDirectional)
    {
        if (map == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(map));
        _map = map;
        _isDirectional = isDirectional;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetEdges(Node node)
    {
        if (node == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("node");

        _map.InitializeKeyCollection(node);
        return _map[node];
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAllUniquesEdges()
    {
        var associationIds = new HashSet<Guid>();
        foreach (var item in _map.Values.SelectMany(v => v)) 
        {
            //If graph is non directional, we don't want the two edges A->B & B->A.
            if (!associationIds.Add(item.AssociationId)) continue;

            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

The creation of a `Graph` is somehow complex, so I created a `IGraphBuilder<T>`.

```
public interface IGraphBuilder<T> where T : Edge
{
    IEnumerable<Node> NodesInGraph { get; }
    IGraph<T> Build();
}

public interface IWeightedGraphBuilder : IGraphBuilder<WeightedEdge>
{
    IWeightedGraphBuilder AddEdge(Node a, Node b, int weight);
}

public class WeightedGraphBuilder : IWeightedGraphBuilder
{
    private ICollectionDictionary<Node, WeightedEdge> _map;
    private bool _hasBeenBuilt;
    private bool _isDirectional;

    public IEnumerable<Node> NodesInGraph => _map.Keys.ToList();
    public bool GeneratedGraphIsDirectional => _isDirectional;

    public WeightedGraphBuilder(bool isDirectional)
    {
        _isDirectional = isDirectional;
        _map = new CollectionDictionary<Node, WeightedEdge>();
        _hasBeenBuilt = false;
    }

    public IWeightedGraphBuilder AddEdge(Node nodeA, Node nodeB, int weight)
    {
        if (nodeA == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("a");

        _map.InitializeKeyCollection(nodeA);

        if (nodeB == null) { return this; }

        _map.InitializeKeyCollection(nodeB);

        ICollection<WeightedEdge> edgesA = _map[nodeA];

        var associationId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var edgeAToB = new WeightedEdge(nodeA, nodeB, weight, associationId);

        edgesA.Add(edgeAToB);

        if (!_isDirectional)
        {
            var edgesB = _map[nodeB];
            var edgeBToA = new WeightedEdge(nodeB, nodeA, weight, associationId);
            edgesB.Add(edgeBToA);
        }

        return this;
    }

    public IGraph<WeightedEdge> Build()
    {
        if (_hasBeenBuilt) throw new InvalidOperationException("Graph has already been built using this builder");
        _hasBeenBuilt = true;

        return new Graph<WeightedEdge>(_map, _isDirectional);
    }
}
```

An example use would be :

```
class Example
{
    void Test()
    {
        IWeightedGraphBuilder bob = new WeightedGraphBuilder(false);
        bob.AddEdge(new Node("a"), new Node("b"), 3);
        bob.AddEdge(new Node("a"), new Node("c"), 2);
        bob.AddEdge(new Node("b"), new Node("d"), 10);

        IGraph<WeightedEdge> graph = bob.Build();
    }
}
```

I've unit tested this code (except the builder, but it works according to the unit test that uses it, tests will come later, oops). I want to know if there's anything smelly in there or things that could be optimized.

The full code can be found on https://github.com/topinfrassi01/GraphTheories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was I so naive in 2015! I had a flash during my sleep. Why would `AddEdge` have the possibility to add a single `Node`? That seems to break the Single Responsibility Principle. To fix this problem, I added an `AddNode` method, which initializes an empty collection for the `_map`'s `Node`. The `AddEdge` method then calls `AddNode` on both the nodes of the new `Edge`.

```
public IWeightedGraphBuilder AddNode(Node node)
{
    if (node == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(node));

    _map.InitializeKeyCollection(node);

    return this;
}

public IWeightedGraphBuilder AddEdge(Node nodeA, Node nodeB, int weight)
{
    if (nodeA == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nodeA));
    if (nodeB == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nodeB));

    AddNode(nodeA);
    AddNode(nodeB);

    //The rest is the same
}
```

This way, the `AddEdge` method cannot add a single node like it's done in the previous implementation, this keeps this method's responsibility count to *one*.

Answer (score 3):

**Node:**

- `Equals(Node other)` will throw `NullReferenceException` when called with `null`
- `GetHashCode()` should only return `Name.GetHashCode()` - the multiplication can cause an overflow and two distinct values of the original hash can get mapped to the same value
- `ToString()` instead of `this.GetType().Name` for the name of the type you can use `nameof(Node)` which is actually a string literal

**Edge:**

If I understand correctly that the point of having `Guid AssociationId` that is set on creation is to label directed edges `x -> y` and `y -> x` with the same `Guid` then I would suggest an alternative implementation:

```
public bool ConnectsSameNodes(Edge edge)
{
    if (edge == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(edge));
    }

    return (From.Equals(edge.From) && To.Equals(edge.To)) ||
           (From.Equals(edge.To) && To.Equals(edge.From));
}
```

This way, `Guid AssociationId` can be removed from the class completely.

Comment: I use `this.GetType().Name` to deal with the inheritance. The hashcode is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613102/why-use-a-prime-number-in-hashcode) and the `AssociationId` is used to deal with cases where two distinct edges connect the same nodes : `A->B` and `A->B` would be possible.

Comment: Regarding the `GetHashCode()`, the link only explains why multiplication by primes is used to combine **multiple** hash codes of multiple fields into one hash code. When you are using only one hash code of a single field, it is better to just return it. You achieve better performance and better distribution that way.

Comment: Fine by me, you're right! :)

Comment: @Martin mind elaborating on what you mean by "nameof() is actually a string literal"?

Comment: @RubberDuck Sure, when you write `nameof(Node)` what actually gets compiled into your assembly is just the [string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) `"Node"`. You can check this by using a tool like ILSpy for decompiling IL. When you decompile an assembly that used `nameof(Node)` in C# code, you will only see `"Node"`.

Comment: Nice! I hadn't realized that `nameof()` was resolved at *compile* time. That will sure beat reflection performance wise.